# parser server client key adding

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I want to add client key to parse server configuraton file ...but when i add and want to use ,my api is not working ...can any one guide me....
my config

```
     var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://xxx:xxx-EB68FQJ:27017/app',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN ||'./cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'xxxx',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'xxxxxx', 
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:3000',
  clientKey:process.env.CLIENT_KEY || 'xxxx',
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] subscriptions
  }
});
```

dashboard config

```
   {
"users":[
  {
  "user":"user", 
  "pass":"pass"
  }
  ],
  "apps": [{
    "serverURL": "http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:3000/parse",
    "appId": "xxxx",
    "masterKey": "xxxxx",
    "clientKey":"xxxxx",
    "appName": "name",
    "iconName": ""
  }],
  "iconsFolder": ""
}
```

Comment: does the issue still persists?

Answer (score 1):

In open sourced Parse server, you only need appId to authenticate your app, therefore client-side keys (clientKey, JavascriptKey, .NetKey...etc) are not needed.